# JavaScript - Get RGBA values from bitmap buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, jimp

Hello I'm using NodeJs and a package named "Jimp".

I'm trying to get the Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha values for each pixel but am having trouble.

Here's my code:

```
Jimp.read("https://i.imgur.com/eOu89DY.png").then((image) => {


console.log(image)

for (var y = 0; y < image.bitmap.height; y = y + 3) {
  for (var x = 0; x < image.bitmap.width; x = x + 3) {


  //--Returns the whole bitmap buffer
  console.log(red)
  var red = image.bitmap.data;

  }
}
```

and here's the example usage from https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp :

```
image.scan(0, 0, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height, function(x, y, idx) {
  // x, y is the position of this pixel on the image
  // idx is the position start position of this rgba tuple in the bitmap Buffer
  // this is the image

  var red = this.bitmap.data[idx + 0];
  var green = this.bitmap.data[idx + 1];
  var blue = this.bitmap.data[idx + 2];
  var alpha = this.bitmap.data[idx + 3];

  // rgba values run from 0 - 255
  // e.g. this.bitmap.data[idx] = 0; // removes red from this pixel
});
```

Using my code, how could I get the red, green, blue values using variables from the buffer? How do I define IDX like the example usage from the npmjs site???

Comment: Why not use the original sample code? It looks perfect for what you need. I was going to start writing an answer but realized i would mostly be replicating their original sample code.

Comment: Because I tried using it, my full script sends post request, and for some reason it doesn't send all of the post request using the original... I'm trying to recreate my old script from tampermonkey using nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look down a little in the linked page.

> Alternatively, you can manipulate individual pixels using the
> following these functions:
>
> ```
> image.getPixelColor(x, y); // returns the colour of that pixel e.g. 0xFFFFFFFF
> ```
>
> ...
> ...
>
> Two static helper functions exist to convert RGBA values into single integer (hex) values:
>
> ```
> Jimp.rgbaToInt(r, g, b, a); // e.g. converts 255, 255, 255, 255 to
> Jimp.intToRGBA(hex); // e.g. converts 0xFFFFFFFF to {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a:255}
> ```